# tabla cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse

Acabo de realizar mi primer programa autodidacta en eclipse que realiza la suma de 2 vectores como puedo solucionar estos fallos:

> • Línea 1: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s). •    Línea
> 2: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s). •    Línea 5: The
> public type SumaVector must be defined in its own file. • Línea 7:
> Illegal modifier for the method main; only public, protected, private,
> abstract, static, final, synchronized, native & strictfp are
> permitted. •  Línea 13: tabla cannot be resolved to a variable. • Línea
> 14: tabla cannot be resolved to a variable. • Línea 18: Illegal
> modifier for the method llenar; only public, protected, private,
> abstract, static, final, synchronized, native & strictfp are
> permitted. •  Línea 23:The word 'llenar' is not correctly spelled
> • Línea 25:Illegal modifier for the method sumar; only public,
> protected, private, abstract, static, final, synchronized, native &
> strictfp are permitted •  Línea 26:>              int suma =0;> • Línea
> 31: The word 'sumar' is not correctly. spelled •  Línea 32: Syntax
> error on token "}", { expected.

```
module SumaVectorDebugger {
module SumaVector {
import java.util.Scanner;
    

public class SumaVector{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner tec = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Introduce el numero de elementos del vector");
            int n = tec.nextInt();
            int [] vec = new int [n];
            vec = llenar(n);
            int suma = sumar(tabla);
            System.out.println("La suma es:" + suma);

        }

        private static int[] llenar(int n) {
            int [] tabla = new int [n];
            for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
            tabla [i] = i * 10;
            return tabla;
        }   //llenar tabla

        public static int sumar (int [] tabla) {
            int suma =0;
            int n = tabla.length;
            for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
            suma= tabla[i];
            return suma;
        }   //sumar tabla
    }
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto te sea de utilidad, no voy a entrar en tu método de implementación, simplemente voy a comentar lo que he visto:

EN LA ESTRUCTURACIÓN DE ECLIPSE:

Las clases Java se organizan en paquetes. Una vez creada una clase, en la parte superior (la cabecera) se hace referencia al paquete del cual contiene y a las implementaciones. En mi opinión, no habría que poner las dos líneas module del comienzo. Como no estoy informado de eso no voy a decir nada al respecto, pero creo que sin esas líneas debería funcionar.

EN EL CÓDIGO DE TU IMPLEMENTACIÓN:

1. Dentro del método main, cuando llamas a la función sumar, tienes que pasarle un parámetro declarado previamente dentro del propio método o de la clase. En este caso, tendrías que pasarle vec, pues ya lo has declarado y lo has inicializado con la función llenar.
2. Método llenar y método sumar: Un array tiene un total de N posiciones. Como empieza en la posición 0, es decir, tabla[0], llegará desde la posición 0 a la N-1. Si no lograste entender esto, analízalo o comprueba esta información en google. Es por esto que en los dos bucles for, aparecerá, en tiempos de ejecución una excepción OutOfBoundsException...
   El bucle quedaría así: for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
3. En el método sumar:
   Cuando quieras sumar varias posiciones seguidas de un vector, o incrementar el valor de una variable se hace uso de "+=". Tendrías que hacer  suma+= tabla[i]; , de lo  contrario, se quedaría guardado únicamente el valor N-1 del array, que devolvería como valor suma del array. Eso es claramente falso.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumaVector {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tec = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce el numero de elementos del vector");
        int n = tec.nextInt();
        int [] vec = new int [n];
        vec = llenar(n);
        int suma = sumar(vec);
        System.out.println("La suma es:" + suma);

    }

    private static int[] llenar(int n) {
        int [] tabla = new int [n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        tabla [i] = i * 10;
        return tabla;
    }   //llenar tabla

    public static int sumar (int [] tabla) {
        int suma =0;
        int n = tabla.length;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        suma+= tabla[i];
        
        
        return suma;
    }   //sumar tabla
    
}
```

Espero que haya sido de ayuda. Mucha suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias esta muy bien la verdad eres un máquiina.